# Android - My onPostExecute in AsyncTask is not getting called

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have been trying to fetch JSON objects in my Django REST Framework API. The algorithm for this called within the onPostExecute of my AsyncTask but it seems that it is not being called as when I debug it doesn't go there. Nothing fatal seems to be appearing in my logcat except that there is nothing in my array that should contain data from the DRF API.

I have two activities that calls my AsyncTask from my `WSAdapter` class. One is for logging in and the other is for listing all posts once logged in.

The logging in works just fine but listing the posts doesn't.

My code is below:

Posts.java

```
public class Posts extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView postsSect;
    Button postsDoneBtn;
    WSAdapter.SendAPIRequests PostsHelper;
    StringBuilder postsBuffer = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        PostsDetails postDetailsHelper = new PostsDetails();
        postDetailsHelper.ListPosts();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);

        PostsDetails postDetailsHelper = new PostsDetails();

        postsDoneBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PostsDoneButton);

        postDetailsHelper.callPostDetails("192.168.0.18:8000/api");
        postDetailsHelper.ListPosts();
        postDetailsHelper.postDetailsCalled('n');

        postsDoneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Posts.this, MainActivity.class));

            }
        });
    }

    public class PostsDetails {
        //String post_title, post_content;
        ArrayList<Integer> post_id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> post_title = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> post_content = new ArrayList<String>();

        boolean isPDCalled;

        // sets if Post details are called
        boolean postDetailsCalled(char called) {
            if (called == 'y'){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        // checks if postsDetails functions are called for AsyncTask
        boolean getIsPDCalled(){
            return isPDCalled;
        }

        // calls the execute for AsyncTask
        private void callPostDetails(String theurl){
            PostsHelper = new WSAdapter.SendAPIRequests();
            // sets if post details are called
            postDetailsCalled('y');
            // executes AsyncTask
            PostsHelper.execute(theurl);
        }

        // sets values for the posts arrays
        public void setPost(int p_id, String p_title, String p_content) {
            post_id.add(p_id);
            post_title.add(p_title);
            post_content.add(p_content);
        }

        // Lists the posts from the database
        public void ListPosts() {
            /////////// add functionality if a post was deleted and was clicked
            postsSect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PostsSection);
            postsSect.setText(post_title.get(post_title.size()) + "\n");
            for (int i = post_id.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                postsSect.append(post_title.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WSAdapter.java

```
public class WSAdapter extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    static public class SendAPIRequests extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        // Add a pre-execute thing

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            Log.e("TAG", params[0]);
            Log.e("TAG", params[1]);
            String data = "";

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            try {

                // Sets up connection to the URL (params[0] from .execute in "login")
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();

                // Sets the request method for the URL
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                // Tells the URL that I am sending a POST request body
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                // To write primitive Java data types to an output stream in a portable way
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
                // Writes out a byte to the underlying output stream of the data posted from .execute function
                wr.writeBytes("postData=" + params[1]);
                // Flushes the postData to the output stream
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

                // Representing the input stream
                InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

                // Preparing input stream bytes to be decoded to charset
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                StringBuilder dataBuffer = new StringBuilder();

                // Translates input stream bytes to charset
                int inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                while (inputStreamData != -1) {
                    char current = (char) inputStreamData;
                    inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                    // concatenates data characters from input stream
                    dataBuffer.append(current);
                }
                data = dataBuffer.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                // Disconnects socket after using
                if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }

            Log.e("TAG", data);
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // expecting a response code fro my server upon receiving the POST data
            Log.e("TAG", result);

            Posts.PostsDetails postsHelper = new Posts().new PostsDetails();

            // For posts
            try {
                if (postsHelper.getIsPDCalled()){
                    JSONObject pJObj = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray pJObjArray = pJObj.getJSONArray("posts");

                    for (int i = 0; i < pJObjArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject pJObj_data = pJObjArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        postsHelper.setPost(pJObj_data.getInt("id"), "post_title", "post_content");
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                //Toast.makeText(JSonActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Json","Exception = "+e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button LoginButton;
    EditText uUserName, uPassWord;
    WSAdapter.SendAPIRequests AuthHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //SetupHomeBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.SetupHomeBtn);

        LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LoginButton);

        uUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LoginUserBox);
        uPassWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LoginPassBox);

        //AuthHelper = new WSAdapter().new SendDeviceDetails();

        // Moves user to the main page after validation
        LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // gets the username and password from the EditText
                String strUserName = uUserName.getText().toString();
                String strPassWord = uPassWord.getText().toString();

                // API url duh
                String APIUrl = "http://192.168.0.18:8000/token-auth/";

                // If the user is authenticated, then transfer to the MainActivity page
                if (APIAuthentication(strUserName, strPassWord, APIUrl)){
                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Posts.class));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private boolean APIAuthentication(String un, String pw, String url){
        // when it wasn't static -> AuthHelper = new WSAdapter().new SendAPIRequests();
        AuthHelper = new WSAdapter.SendAPIRequests();

        JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
        try {
            // Attempt to input info to the Django API
            postData.put("username", un);
            postData.put("password", pw);

            // Putting the data to be posted in the Django API
            AuthHelper.execute(url, postData.toString());

            return true;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I was expecting my onPostExecute to be called and store data for my posts arrays.

Comment: add your async class

Comment: I just did. Sorry I thought I placed it

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is a nice example of async tasks. The problem here is when you call an async task then the code below will continue to execute even when the async task hasn't finished. So what happens in your case:

- You fetch the posts and then ask to display them on the exact moment that the async function is still getting the posts. So of course the List is empty.

You can fix this by using the await keyword. This keyword stops the rest of your code from executing until that line has been executed. So change:

```
postDetailsHelper.callPostDetails("192.168.0.18:8000/api");
```

to:

```
await postDetailsHelper.callPostDetails("192.168.0.18:8000/api");
```

Now the reason that the login does work is because you call that function within the if statement. If you would store the return value of that function in a boolean first then it wouldn't work either.